# Troubles with overlay window

Tags: android, overlay

I'm writing an android application which simulates mouse.
I used code from pocketmagic.com for cursor overlay
And on my Droid Maxx (4.4.4) it works
But on Minix NEO X5 mini (4.4.2) (set top box) it doesn't
Here's the code

```
mView = new OverlayView(this);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,//TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,//TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE |
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN, //will cover status bar as well!!!
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
    params.setTitle("Cursor");
    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    wm.addView(mView, params);
```

And

```
class OverlayView extends ViewGroup {
private Paint mLoadPaint;
boolean mShowCursor;

Bitmap cursor;
public int x = 0,y = 0;

public void Update(int nx, int ny) {
    x = nx; y = ny;
}
public void ShowCursor(boolean status) {
    mShowCursor = status;
}
public boolean isCursorShown() {
    return mShowCursor;
}

public OverlayView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    cursor = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_cursor);

    mLoadPaint = new Paint();
    mLoadPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mLoadPaint.setTextSize(10);
    mLoadPaint.setARGB(255, 255, 0, 0);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    //canvas.drawText("Hello World", 0, 0, mLoadPaint);
    if (mShowCursor) canvas.drawBitmap(cursor,x,y,null);
}

@Override
protected void onLayout(boolean arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4) {
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Find out that it is **actually work** but only on left part of the screen (0-855 pixels) Also "Show screen repaint" in dev options force that part of screen blink more frequently than right part. Screen resolution is 1920x1080

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I caught that canvas in method onDraw has wrong dimensions. The only way I've found is to replace WRAP_CONTENT with screen size

Answer (score 0):

Try decreasing your API level and min SDK requirement and see if it works.

Comment: My API already at 4.2 level. But a just was thinking about it. Maybe it's because Minix output is not screen, but HDMI?